# Using amsart indirectly as a base class of another class changes the way the date is printed

Tags: documentclass-writing, amsart

I created a custom document class based on `amsart`. When I used it instead of `amsart`, to my great surprise this changed the way the date is printed in the footnote of the first page: instead of

> Date: May 3, 2021.

I've got

> Received by the editors May 3, 2021.

Not only the sudden change in behaviour is unexpected and looks wrong, but I find weird the idea that the author should set the date to the (possibly unknown) date when the document shall be received by some editors.

Is this a bug? How to keep the "usual" date line format when using `amsart` as a base class of a custom class?

Here is an example to reproduce the behaviour (tested with `pdflatex`):

```tex
%% file: paper.tex
\documentclass{myamsart}
\title{The Pythagorean theorem}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

```tex
%% file: myamsart.cls
\ProvidesClass{myamsart}[2021/05/03]
\LoadClass{amsart}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amsart does

```
\def\@tempb{amsart}
\ifx\@classname\@tempb
  \newcommand{\datename}{\textit{Date}:}
\else
  \newcommand{\datename}{Received by the editors}
\fi
```

so your class can redefine `\datename` to be anything you like after loading `amsart`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the reason for this behaviour? How could this conditional be useful? It is strange to have to patch this in my class.

Comment: @Alexey amsart is designed to fit the in-house production processes of the AMS, they probably have a variant with a different name which then produces the received by editors text.

Comment: @Alexey -- The AMS does not use any author-assigned dates in its publications (except in actual text).  Only "editorial" dates are published.  The original version of `amsart` was based on `article`, with relatively minimal changes to adhere to AMS editorial policy.  Among the policy changes was making it difficult (if not impossible) for authors to use the date as originally defined, to avoid the necessity of changing it in the proofreading process, thus also avoiding "editorial errors".